# Trapping SIGINT so that the process kills itself

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, signals, trap

So section 5 from [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap) made sense to me and I wanted to implement it. I have this bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cp aux.sh aux.sh.bak

cleanup() {
    cp aux.sh.bak aux.sh
    rm -rf aux.sh.bak
}

trap 'cleanup; trap - SIGINT; kill -s SIGINT "$$"' SIGINT
trap cleanup EXIT

echo "Hold this for now" >> aux.sh

read -rp "Hit Enter to finish"

exit 0
```

But, when running it, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I get a this error:

```
Hit Enter to finish^Ccp: cannot stat 'aux.sh.bak': No such file or directory
```

I don't know why this error happens. But my guess is that `cleanup` is being run again as a result of the `kill` command.

What am I doing wrong? How to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, `EXIT` traps are invoked regardless of the exit cause. In your case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> causes the `SIGINT` trap to run, then when the script kills itself, the `EXIT` trap runs.

As you suspect, the `cleanup` function thus ends up being called twice.

The wiki page you referred to explains how to deal with this (in bash only):

> So to clean up, just trap EXIT and call a cleanup function from there. Don't trap a bunch of signals.

Comment: This is working: `trap 'trap SIGINT; kill -s SIGINT "$$"' SIGINT; trap cleanup EXIT`

Comment: I’m curious: what’s the use of the `SIGINT` trap? There doesn’t seem to be much point in it if all it does is untrap and resend the signal.

Comment: If I don’t trap it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> kills whatever command my script is running at the moment but it will not kill the script which is undesirable in my case.

Comment: That’s surprising, the default behaviour in bash is to exit scripts if a command they run is stopped with Ctrl-C. Perhaps the command in question in your case isn’t setting its exit information correctly...

Comment: That is probable, yes.